# how do I activate a sub menu route from a main menu route - vue-router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Hi all I need some help with activating a sub menu route from a main menu route - vue-router. I have the following code in my app.js for routing. The children object has a sub-route that I want highlighted when the main menu nav link (transactions) is clicked. In my browser URL I see http://localhost:3000/transactions/transaction_history which tells me that it is going to the destination I want but I have no clue to get the sub-route active from the main nav? Any help will be great.

app.js

```
const routes = [
    {
        name: 'transactions',
        path: 'transactions/transaction_history',
        component: transactions,
        children: [
            {
                name: 'transaction-history',
                path: '/transactions/transaction_history',
                component: transaction_history
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

In my navigation.vue I have

```
<li class="u-nav__tab-item pull-left">
    <router-link v-bind:class="{ 'u-nav__tab-item--active' : $route.name === 'transactions' }" :to="{ name: 'transactions', path: '/transactions' }" exact>Transactions
        <div class="u-nav__dropdown-arrow pull-right"></div>
    </router-link>
</li>
```

And in my transactions.vue template I have this link which is the first-child of the sub menu

```
<li class="o-pf-list__item o-pf-list__item--border o-pf-list__item--line-height" :class="{ 'u-nav__tab-item--active-border-left' : $route.name === 'transaction-history' }">
    <router-link v-bind:class="{ 'u-nav__tab-item--active' : $route.name === 'transaction-history' }" :to="{ name: 'transaction-history', path: '/transactions/transaction_history' }" exact>Transaction History</router-link>
</li>
```

Example of what I want when the main nav is clicked. This is the sub menu first child.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, your problem seems to be that you've forgotten that child routes inherit the path from their parent. You only need to specify `/transactions` for the parent path, and `transaction_history` for the child path. Also, your parent path doesn't explicitly start at the path root `/` while your child route does. That's confusing.

I'm also not sure why you're specifying the `to` attribute on your router links. Those seem unnecessary, as does the `exact` attribute. You're conflating a lot of features that I think you don't need here.

Comment: I had it like that at first, though when I select the transactions tab it does not highlight the first child of the sub-routes like I demonstrated in the image above. that is the part that I need working.

Answer (score 0):

```
const routes = [
    {
        name: 'transactions',
        path: '/transactions',
        component: transactions,
        children: [
            {
                name: 'transaction-history',
                path: '/transaction_history',
                component: transaction_history
            }
        ]
    }
]


<li class="u-nav__tab-item pull-left">
    <router-link v-bind:class="{ 'u-nav__tab-item--active' : $route.name === 'transactions' }" :to="{ path: '/transactions' }">Transactions
        <div class="u-nav__dropdown-arrow pull-right"></div>
    </router-link>
</li>



<li class="o-pf-list__item o-pf-list__item--border o-pf-list__item--line-height" :class="{ 'u-nav__tab-item--active-border-left' : $route.name === 'transaction-history' }">
    <router-link v-bind:class="{ 'u-nav__tab-item--active' : $route.name === 'transaction-history' }" :to="{ path: '/transactions/transaction_history' }">Transaction History</router-link>
</li>
```